# How to count occurrences of "1 1", "-1 1", "1 -1", and "-1 -1" in a file using Python?

Tags: python, counter, python-3.4

I have data file that contains values in the following format:

```
1 1
-1 1
1 -1
-1 -1
...
```

I need to count increment a variable each time I notice an occurrence of these. For example, `PositiveNegative += 1` when I encounter `1 -1` and `NegativeNegative += 1` when I encounter `-1 -1`.

So far I have this:

```
PositivePositive = 0
f1 = open("200_sample.txt", 'r')
v = f1.read()
for line in v:
    if "1 1" in line:
        PositivePositive +=1
```

But it doesn't count any occurrence of `1 1`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `v = f1.read()`, that reads all the contents of the file into one long string, called `v`. When you iterate over it with `for line in v:`, it's looking at a *single character* at a time. So, of course, it won't find three characters within a single character.

To fix this, simply don't `read()` the file object. You can iterate over it directly, and the file reader will iterate line by line:

```
lines = {'-1 1':0, '1 -1':0, '1 1':0, '-1 -1':0}
with open("200_sample.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines[line.strip()] += 1
```

Also, use the `with` context manager to automatically close the file once that block has ended.

You can store each kind of line as a dictionary key and then update that key's value when you see it.

Comment: Note that once fixed as TigerhawkT3 suggested, your code will be bugged since "1 1" in "-1 1" is True, you probably don't want to increment in that case though...

Comment: A preliminary `if '-' in line:` with some extra branches would take care of that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I noticed. Right now, when I add the count for all those 4 cases, the total comes out to be more than the total values(lines) in the file. Could you update your answer to fix this? I'm working on it as well.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Awesome! You're a life-saver. I have an 'advanced data mining' homework due tomorrow, and I really needed to count those values.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a default dictionary with a `for` loop

```
from collections import defaultdict

myfile = open("thefile.txt")

mycountdict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

for line in myfile.readlines():
    mycountdict[line] += 1
```

Then just `print` or `return` the desired output from the `defaultdict`

```
print(mycountdict["1 1\n"])
```

Comment: You may have some pesky `\n` characters since `readlines()` reads your data in as strings, such that you need to include this character in the key when you try to return it. Alternatively you could have python strip the `\n` character from the string as you put it into your dictionary.